# Tag delimiters are not consistent in posthistory.xml

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, data-dump

In the September 2011, December 2011, and several of the closed site data dumps the tag history is not delimited consistently across all sites. As an example from IT Security:

```
  <row Id="48" PostHistoryTypeId="3" PostId="26" RevisionGUID="6b0fa8fb-4ae4-4d8c-8f91-d0272b10d9e0" CreationDate="2010-11-11T22:04:24.517" UserId="4" Text="ébestöpracticesàéwebsiteösecurityà" />
```

Note the `ébestöpracticesàéwebsiteösecurityà` as the text for the list of tags.

This goes against the behaviour I had expected, namely as in the Gaming dump:

```
&lt;teamfortress2&gt;&lt;strategy&gt;&lt;multiplayer&gt;&lt;fps&gt;
```

It also appears to just be the `posthistory.xml` file that is affected, as the `posts.xml` file contains the <> delimiters as expected.

---

#### Update

I've taken another look at this, it seems to only affect newer sites (in both Sep & Dec dumps), which would suggest a change (charset configuration?) that was not retrospectively applied, and my incomplete download of the September dump indicates the change was made somewhere between GIS and Unix, since GIS is okay and Unix is not. (Everything else inbetween is only partially downloaded on my laptop)

Comment: This also impacts Data Explorer, which has similarly broken tag delimiters in its `PostHistory` tables for those sites.

Comment: Also note that other characters are affected: `-` appears as `ö`, `.` appears as `n̂`, `#` appears as `ñ`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will be an update to the data explorer later today.  The dump will be revised in 3 months with the corrected tags.

**UPDATE** Data.SE has been updated - check: https://data.stackexchange.com/it%20security/q/122504/ for validation